# The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've got a time-triggered Azure Function through which I push some message in my Azure Service Bus topic. Now, the expectation is whenever a message is received in the topic it will trigger another function which is a topic-triggered function. Unfortunately, when I check for messages in the topic subscription through Service Bus Explorer tool, it doesn't show any message received. Also I can see this error in the function console :  `The 'myFunc' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed`

I'm not sure where am I going wrong here. I've defined my topic-triggered function like this:

```
   [FunctionName("myFunc")]
                public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic-name", "subs-name", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string message, ILogger log)
                { ... }
```

Note that I've got the latest versions of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` & `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus`  installed(however dont know why both shows a warning). Is it because of any issue with the versions?

[image]

My host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "fun_name": "Information"
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the version of function you are using?

Comment: @BowmanZhu it's v2

Comment: Show your host.json

Comment: @TimP. added in the main contect

Comment: Can you show the .csproj file of your function app?

Comment: On my side it is normal, the problem is most likely a component problem.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the .csproj file on my side, it works fine on local.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

There should be no problems, you may face component conflicts.

Comment: I upgraded to these packages and it started working - (1) <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.1.1" /> & (2)
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.1" />